# Windows Phone - ToggleSwitch in LongListSelector (not changing when scrolling)

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, gesture, longlistselector

This is my LongListSelector in my page.xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="ModuleList" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource LLSFloatingScrollbarStyle}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModuleListTemplate}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}"/>
```

My template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ModuleListTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="{Binding StackModuleMargin}">
...
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch" 
                              Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,4,0,-26" Padding="0"
                              Content="" SwitchForeground="{StaticResource TrackitoOrange}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleCheck, Mode=TwoWay}">
                 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                             <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.LockSwitchTapCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                       </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
...
```

The problem is that click is raised when I just scroll with list. Yes I have my finger in place where is toggle but I want to fix it when I scroll then toggle shoudn't be changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a probably a design issue you should explore if you have two competing tap events in your UI.

That said, you could override OnScroll and mark the event as handled at the original level so it doesn't bubble up to your toggle button.

Comment: LongListSelector doesn't have OnScroll event.

Comment: I think you could use OnManipulationStarted/Completed instead.